# Why is my WHERE clause not return the CustomerIDs that are also in the Orders table?

Tags: sql

My SQL statements are not returning any results. I am using the table that are on the www.w3schools.com web site. I want to have all of the customer IDS in my Customers table match all of the CustomerIDS in the Orders table. The SQL statement works that it goes through the table and checks every CustomerID to every Orders.CustomersID and when it finds a match doesn't it return that record.

**Question: Why does the SQL not return the row when both customerIDS are equal because there are values that will return true?**

SQL Statement:

```
     SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Customers.CustomersID = Orders.CustomersID;
```

One last thought: What is the best free SQL database that can be downloaded without a lot of hassle for home use?

Comment: You haven't specified what orders is in your SQL statement.  You need some sort of a join.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Customers.* 
FROM Customers 
JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID;
```

Comment: Syntax error in FROM clause. --> Remember I am running this in the w3schools browser because I have not yet received the correct permissions on my company server yet.   ---->  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Comment: Works like a champ on w3schools site for me, but had to fix your column name (CustomerID not CustomersID)

Comment: That is standard SQl, there is no syntax error there. Perhaps you mistyped it.

Answer (score 0):

- You need a query like this: 
  `SELECT * 
  FROM Customers c 
  INNER JOIN Orders o on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID;`
- w3schools is a very [bad resource](http://www.w3fools.com/).
- Selecting the best database is a bad question for stackoverflow. But the answer is PostgreSQL. (And lots of other DBMSs would fit the bill for you as well.)

Comment: No value given for one or more required parameters. --> this is what the result said.  I am running these examples on --> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all -- is the location that I run all of the examples until i get access to my company database.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want customers that have orders then use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
WHERE CustomerID IN 
    (SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders)
```

If you use a `JOIN` you may get multiple records per customer (if the customer has multiple orders).  You can solve that with `DISTINCT` but IMHO a `IN` clause is cleaner (and likely faster)

Comment: correct that you avoid duplicates, but possibly MUCH more expensive because of the subquery. Another (better) way to remove duplicates is do a JOIN then a GROUP BY.